# Shall monsters reveal their traits

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

When the haunt begins, shall the betrayal reveal to everyone their stats - might, speed, etc. or they should keep them secret?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All information in the traitor's tome is for the traitor's eyes only. Generally, this includes monster stats as well. If the heroes are allowed to know it; then it would be written in their scenario rules as well.

However, because die rolls need to be made publicly; the first time a monster actually uses one of its stats; the heroes will find out what value that stat is. Though many scenarios have the monsters change stats based on number of turns or some other value; in which case the heroes will only know the monster's current stat; not what it might become later.

From [the official FAQ](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/ah/FAQ_BHotH_102605-2.pdf):

> When do the heroes find out the traits of a monster?
>
> > When the monster has to roll dice for a trait. All dice rolls are open.

Also:

> How much do you have to reveal about what you are doing to the other side?
>
> > You should announce the purpose of any action you are taking to the other side -- for instance, "I
> >     am making an exorcism roll now," or "This roll is to see whether the house blows up." You don't
> >     need to reveal what number you need to roll.

Also see [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23266/if-a-hero-makes-a-speed-sanity-other-non-might-attack-when-does-the-traitor-rev) dealing with when you are allowed to know whether or not a monster actually has a particular stat.